# Dead keys - combining functionality -inconsistent

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard, keyboard-layout, unicode

I don't completely understand dead keys. 
The dead acute for example always behaves in the following way: You have to know which character is compatible and then you can type that character with an acute. If you type the dead acute twice, it will appear after the previous character – unlike the combining acute.
Now, I've found that dead_hook behaves completely differently, in that it also behaves like any combining character. You can type it after any other character twice and it will modify that character like a combining character!
On the other hand, the dead_horn character doesn't seem to work at all.

Can anyone explain these inconsistencies? Is there a way to get this amazing functionality of the dead_hook with other dead keys too?

Comment: As an alternative, which side-steps the strangeness, have you tried using Compose instead of Dead Keys?

Comment: @roaima I don't know how that works. Sounds interesting.

Comment: The triple { Compose a ' } gives á. The triple { Compose o " } gives ö. And { Compose o / } gives ø. And so on. No keys are dead - the quote characters remain as quote characters - it's the introduction of the composition sequence that generates the non-keyboard character.

Comment: @roaima So, the uk layout that I don't usually use has Compose mapped to alt-gr. But how do I use it? Alt-Gr doesn't seem to offer more functionality than before. I have tried to to use your triple but I don't know how to execute it.

Comment: Okay, I've found a solution. The keyboard settings had an option to map the Compose key to the third level of many keys. Thank you :)

Comment: It's either "Tap AltGr then a then accent" or "Hold AltGr (like it's Shift) tap a then accent". I'm not at my keyboard at the moment and I really can't remember which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behavior seems to be that there are rules like this for the combining_hook:
`<dead_hook> <dead_hook>          : "̉"   U0309                # COMBINING HOOK ABOVE`

Custom rules like this can be set in ~/.XCompose
In the past, this must have required XIM or UIM from what I have read but XIM breaks it for me. It works for me without XIM or UIM.